# Strike chest in "S'lach lanu" on Shabas?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, shemoneh-esrei, mistakes

Suppose someone is praying *maariv*, *shacharis*, or *mincha* on *Shabas*, starts the weekday *amida*'s blessings, and then realizes, amid those weekday blessings, that he should be saying the *amida* of *Shabas*. As ruled in *Orach Chayim* 268:2, he should continue through to the end of whatever blessing he's amid, and then start the *Shabas* blessing. The reason he continues with the blessing he's amid, *Mishna B'rura* 2 writes, is that that blessing is really suitable for *Shabas* in theory.

Now, during the third weekday-specific blessing ("*S'lach lanu*"), it's customary to strike one's chest with his fist. Suppose someone realizes, after starting that blessing but before reaching the part where he strikes his chest, that he should be saying the *amida* of *Shabas*. Then, per the preceding paragraph, he should finish "*S'lach lanu*". I wonder whether he should strike his chest. Arguably, yes, why not? On the other hand, though, (a) maybe, just as we don't (usually) say *viduy* on *Shabas*, there's some reason not to strike the chest on *Shabas*, and (b) maybe in order to save oneself the shame of revealing he started the weekday blessings, he can omit striking his chest. Does anyone have any sources on this, please?

Comment: Classic strike-chest-while-folding-arms situation.

Comment: Some have a custom not to strike the chest even on weekdays when tachanun is not recited. Also, some have a custom to strike the chest during the first line of Avinu Malkeinu (at least, in Ashkenazic rite) _except_ on Rosh haShana when we don't generally say vidui.

Comment: @DoubleAA re your second comment's first sentence: if you can source that, it sounds like the germ of an answer.

Comment: msh210 I saw it in a teshuva in Rivevot Ephraim. Now I have to go find it again....

Comment: Got it! http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1534&st=&pgnum=94&hilite=

Comment: @msh210 That is the [Chabad custom](http://www.sichosinenglish.org/books/sefer-haminhagim/12.htm) (not to strike whenever we don't say tachnun, and similarly not at Maariv).

Comment: @Michoel, well, if you beat DoubleAA to posting it as an answer... `:-)`

Comment: Well it doesn't answer for those who don't follow this custom.

Comment: @Michoel, right, but it's a partial answer.

Comment: @DoubleAA , The Rivevos Ephraim is 8:87:5,he quotes the Mekor Chaim who says what you stated.

Comment: @sam He mentions it earlier too. See the link in [my above comment](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26337/strike-chest-in-slach-lanu-on-shabas#comment59638_26337).

Comment: Well if rabbinic prohibitions are waived for כבוד הבריות I am sure that a relatively late minhag could be waived as well.

Answer (score 4):

On Rosh Hashana, we recite Avinu Malekenu. However, some authorities maintain that one should omit the verse *chatanu l'fanecha* because it is like a *viduy*. The majority of the poskim hold that one may recite the verse as it is meant as a supplication, not a confession. However, **they caution that one should not strike his chest as usual, lest it seem like a confession**.

(I'm basically quoting from the Artscroll R. H. Machzor, Nusach Ashkenaz, p. 553. I had a vague memory that they discussed such a thing and indeed found it there, but I don't have the time to find the real sources. Sorry.)

Comment: This might be particular to Rosh Hashanah since we aren't supposed to confess sins on Rosh Hashana.

Comment: We aren't supposed to confess sins on Shabbos either, as mentioned in the question: "we don't (usually) say *viduy* on *Shabbos*"

Comment: Sounds like if this happens on Yom Kippur you would strike

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, it seems that those who daven Mincha late on Erev Shabbos don't strike the chest when saying Slach Lanu. This is printed in the Bobover Siddur, Siddur Harav.

Answer (score 1):

If he strikes his chest, he will publicizing to the whole shul that he goofed.
Therefore, in the interests of kavod habriyos, it is logical that he should not strike his chest.

Answer (score 0):

No.
Source: see bottom of the page of the image attached. On Shabbos we don't say tachanun
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCDCz.jpg

Edit: This is Siddur Tehillat Hashem

Comment: What _sidur_ is this? And I think you should qualify your "No", since afaik most people *do* hit their chests on weekdays _tachanun_ is omitted.

Comment: @msh210 Siddur Tehillat Hashem. It could be only Chabad. I don't know what others do.